# Extracting date from string and saving in new pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

**Background:**

I have a pandas DataFrame containing a `tweet` and `weather` column. The DataFrame columns are current as follows -
[image]

**Objective:**
I am trying to extract the datestamp from the `weather` column (e.g the `datestamp` for row index 0 is '(2020-07-14)') and save it in a new `date` column, with the purpose of filtering on it, e.g filtering to the latest date.

I know how to change a column string value to a `datestamp`, if it were something like '20140512'. However I have no idea how to identify a `datestamp` in the current format and extract that into a new column.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is it always inside of the weather column, in (YYYY-MM-DD) format?

Comment: Hi Derek - yes, the format remains consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this, assuming it's in the weather column and always has the same formatting:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weather'].str.extract('\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\)')[0])
```

or

```
import re
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weather'].apply(lambda x: re.search('\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\)', x).group(1)))
```